# tMap from two tSetGlobalVar

Tags: talend, tmap

I have two tSetGlobalVar in which I store two different columns.
NB_DNCL_OLD and NB_DNCL_NEW.

I am trying to connect them to a tMap component in order to have a single table as output, adding an expression for the difference between both integer variables.
I am able to connect NB_DNCL_OLD as row3 (Main) to tMap but I am not allowed to connect NB_DNCL_NEW to the same tMap.

tMapImage

[image: 1 - tMapImage]

New tsetglobalvars connected to tMap before being connecting to their sources:

[image: 2 - New tsetglobalvars connected to tMap before being connecting to their sources]

Should I use any component between the tSetGlobalVar and the tMap? What am I doing wrong? (I am new to Talend and I have no Java knowledge).

I have just recreated the tsetglobalvar and I have connected them to the tMap without connecting them to their sources (2 tFlowIterate) and this time I was able to connect the second one to the tMap through a lookup but, if I try to reconnect the tsetglobalvars to their sources I have the same problem: I am able to connect just the first as Main and I am not allowed to connect the second.
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Hi' I'm afraid there is something strange in your design. Why don't you simply connect both input table to the tMap? Maybe an example with input and expected data should help to understand your use case.

Comment: @TRF thanks for your answer! I didn't find what doesn't let me do that but I followed your suggestion and by reviewing my design I found that I didn't need the tMap component in order to have an expression between the two tSetGlobalVar. The expected result is sending an e-mail containing the values of the 2 variables and the difference between them and I am able to calculate the new variable directly into the tSendMail component's message. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a good answer from the Talend Community which has helped me to solve my problem from a different perspective:

https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/tMap-from-two-tSetGlobalVar/m-p/39258/highlight/false#M10959